# non-trivial weak solution of SDE

Tags: probability, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Let consider the SDE $dX_t=|X_t|^adW_t$ for $0<a<\frac{1}{2}$

I know that this SDE has non-zero weak solution by Engelbrt & Schmidt's theorem.
But I cannot find weak solution $(X,W)$ with $X\not =0$ explicitly.
Do you konw how to find it ?

Comment: You can obtain a (non-trivial) solution by a random time change of a Brownian motion, see the first part [here](https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/05/17/sdes-under-changes-of-time-and-measure/).

Comment: Thank you!! I understand.